# How does Visual Studio determine typescript base path when not explicitly configured

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, requirejs, typescript, amd

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.
I use external modules to reference the different modules (AMD+require.js)

I have a asp.net web project that have a structure look something like this:

```
App/first/firstmodule.ts
App/second/secondmodule.ts
```

firstmodule.ts looks like this:

```
import first = require("first/firstmodule");
.. do stuff..
```

Notice that secondmodule reference firstmodule relative to a base path. (App/). Visual Studio gives no warnings/errors on this, and everything is fine.

I haven't configured this path 'App/' base path anywhere (as far as I know).

The csproj project settings 'TypeScriptSourceRoot' and 'TypeScriptMapRoot' are not configured.

Where does this 'App/' base path value come from, that Visual Studio obviously knows about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't configured this path 'App/' base path anywhere (as far as I know).

That is correct.

What it does is : It looks at *every* parent folder and appends to see the path. As such this has the potential to be an incorrect assumption and your code will fail at runtime if you don't have a good base path configured.

Comment: Is this stuff documented anywhere?

Comment: @AndreasPresthammer no

Comment: Would you then configure the base path in the 'TypeScriptSourceRoot' settings?